# Looking for duplicate in local text file

Tags: php

please could someone help me with this duplicate checking function. I'm still quite fresh when it comes to PHP, so please excuse me, if this is a simple fix.

I'm storing a list of email addresses to a file called list.txt. Here is the content of the file (each on a new line):

```
bob@foo.com
sam@bar.com
tracy@foobar.com
```

Now I have a function (not working) that should check if email is already in the list:

```
function is_unique($email) {
   $list = file('list.txt');

   foreach($list as $item){
      if($email == $item){
          return false;
          die(); 
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

When I call the function in this test, with an existing email address, it still returns true:

```
if( is_unique('bob@foo.com') ) {
    echo "Email is unique";
} else {
    echo "Duplicate email";
}

// Returns true even though bob@foo.com is in the list
```

I appreciate anyone's input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is fine to use `list` but you must `trim()` the `item` when iterating through the `list` as they still have the linebreak:

```
if($email == trim($item))
```

**Update:** As [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011145/nick) mentioned, the optional flag of `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` would dramatically cut down on execution speed and code:

```
function is_unique($email) {
   $list = file('list.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
   return in_array($email,$list) ? false : true;  
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Forgot about the line breaks. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Using the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag when you use the file function would be a better solution than having to trim it out manually after that

Comment: @Nick - That's a great point, I've added the example and threw in a link to you, hope that's alright.

Answer (score 2):

Either remember to [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your email, or a better solution would be to use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` while you use the [file function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), which would allow you to use PHP's inbuilt array searching (should be faster). For example:

```
function is_unique($email) {
   $list = file('list.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

   return !in_array($email,$list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the file -using fopen- and read every line separately. Then you just simply check if the name is already in there. You can also open it, put the entire file in an array (every line = array row) and throw over an array_unique to filter out doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line and compare the content of that line with your new email.

Something like this:

```
function is_unique($email) 
{
   $file = fopen("list.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

   while(!feof($file))
   {
      if($email == $file){
      return false;
      die();
   }
   fclose($file);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for list all non-duplicate emails:

```
$list=array_unique(file('list.txt'));
```

for check if duplicates exists:

```
$list1=file('list.txt');
$list2=array_unique(file('list.txt'));
count($list1)==count($list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look out for carriage return and line feed at end of each line of file

```
$fp = fopen('emails.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp))
{
   $eml = fgets($fp);
   if(trim($eml, " \n\r") == $email)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
return true;
```